# Allow app analytics opt-out?

Tags: android, ios, appstore, analytics

Given that mobile app analytics reporting can cost a customer data traffic that, unlike a web app, use of the mobile app may otherwise not require, should a mobile app provide a user accessible setting to allow customers to opt out of app analytics collection or reporting?

If and where should a customer be notified that running a given mobile app might capture and transmit analytics data on the app's usage?

Are there any app stores where either of the above is a requirement?

Comment: it sounds like you need user consent in order not to get sued, at list in west Europe and US.

Comment: @ElYusubov: Large parts of Eastern Europe are part of the EU too. The User Consent rule is EU law, so it applies to them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing a user to configure whether background processes like that run is a good idea for user friendliness, or even default to only do this while connected to WiFi. Not only for allowing users to save data usage, but battery life as well.

I believe that listing that an app runs analytics is required to be listed with the other requirements for running the app, though it may be possible to simply list internet access as a general requirement.

I don't think its required to have an app do anything like this, but at least for android users are required to hit an accept button on a list of features the app requires, so there is a notice that an app may do X.